# How to find the critical point for this Coulomb field

Tags: physics, vector-fields, perturbation-theory, electromagnetism

Two equal positive charges are at distance $d$, $-d$ from the origin on the $y$ axis. What is the distance on the $x$ axis beyond which a small perturbation in $y$ will move a particle *away* from the $x$ axis?

My attempt is to consider the y components of electric field where $y<d$ $$\frac{y-d}{(x^2+(y-d)^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{d+y}{(x^2+(d+y)^2)^{3/2}}=0$$
and solve for $x$ as $y/d \to 0$. But this gives me nonsense unsolvable equations.

The answer should be $x = \sqrt{2}d$.

[image]

As illustrated above, We are finding the horizontal distance to where the lines start to curve away.

Answer (score 2):

Due to symmetry, the vertical electric field $E_y$ is always zero at $y = 0$.

$$E_y \equiv \frac{y+d}{(x^2+(y+d)^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{y-d}{(x^2+(y-d)^2)^{3/2}}$$

We want $\partial E_y / \partial y = 0$, where a test particle right on the $x$-axis is no longer stable. Namely, the goal is to find the $x$ value along the $x$-axis ($y = 0$) where the field $E_y$ goes from "squeeze in" $\partial E_y / \partial y < 0$ to "repel" $\partial E_y / \partial y > 0$ (note that we are talking about the field not the potential).

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} &= \frac1{(x^2+(y+d)^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{3(y+d)^2}{(x^2+(y+d)^2)^{5/2}} \\
&\hspace{36pt} + \frac1{(x^2+(y-d)^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{3(y-d)^2}{(x^2+(y-d)^2)^{5/2}} \\
\implies \left. \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} \right|_{y=0} &= \frac2{(x^2+d^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{6 d^2}{(x^2+d^2)^{5/2}} = 2\frac{x^2 - 2d^2}{(x^2+d^2)^{5/2}} 
\end{align}
Setting $(\partial E_y / \partial y)|_{y=0} = 0$ we easily have $x^2 - 2d^2 = 0 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{2} d$ as needed.

#### Alternatively, perturbation (series expansion) as OP intended

The goal is to show the critical point where the vertical electric field $E_y$ at given finite tiny $y>0$ goes from negative (towards the $x$-axis) to positive (away from $x$-axis), where

\begin{align}
E_y &= \frac{d+y}{(x^2+(d+y)^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{d-y}{(x^2+(d-y)^2)^{3/2}} \\
&= \frac{d}{ (x^2 + d^2)^{3/2} } \left( \frac{ 1 + y/d }{ \displaystyle \Bigl( 1 + \frac{ 2dy + y ^2}{ x^2 + d^2 } \Bigr)^{3/2} } -\frac{ 1 - y/d }{ \displaystyle \Bigl( 1 - \frac{ 2dy - y ^2}{ x^2 + d^2 } \Bigr)^{3/2} } \right)\end{align}

Since we are only interested solving $E_y = 0$, the overall factor in front can be dropped for convenience.

$$\begin{aligned}
E_y &\propto \bigl(1 + \frac{y}d \bigr) \left( 1 + \frac{ 2dy + y ^2}{ x^2 + d^2 } \right)^{-3/2} - \bigl(1 - \frac{y}d \bigr) \left( 1 - \frac{ 2dy - y ^2}{ x^2 + d^2 } \right)^{-3/2} \\
&=  \bigl(1 + \frac{y}d \bigr) \left( 1 + \frac{ 2d }{ x^2 + d^2 } \bigl( 1 + \frac{y}{2d}\bigr)y  \right)^{-3/2} - \bigl(1 - \frac{y}d \bigr) \left( 
1 - \frac{ 2d }{ x^2 + d^2 } \bigl( 1 - \frac{y}{2d}\bigr)y \right)^{-3/2}
\end{aligned}$$

Consider the series expansion for $\displaystyle \epsilon \equiv \frac{y}{2d} \ll 1$. **Use the shorthand** $\displaystyle K \equiv \frac{ 4d^2 }{ x^2 + d^2 }$ for this factor that doesn't involve $\epsilon$.

$$\begin{aligned}
E_y &\propto  \bigl(1 + \frac{y}d \bigr) \left( 1 + K \bigl( 1 + \frac{y}{2d}\bigr)\frac{y}{2d}  \right)^{-3/2} - \bigl(1 - \frac{y}d \bigr) \left( 
1 - K \bigl( 1 - \frac{y}{2d}\bigr) \frac{y}{2d} \right)^{-3/2}\\
&=(1 + 2\epsilon ) \bigl( 1 + K ( 1 + \epsilon ) \epsilon  \bigr)^{-3/2} - (1 - 2\epsilon ) \bigl( 
1 - K ( 1 - \epsilon ) \epsilon \bigr)^{-3/2}\\
&=(1 + 2\epsilon ) \left( 1 - \frac32 K (1+\epsilon)\epsilon + \frac1{2!}\frac32 \frac52 K^2 (1+\epsilon)^2\epsilon^2 - \frac1{3!}\frac32 \frac52 \frac72 K^3 (1+\epsilon)^3\epsilon^3 + \cdots \right) \\
&\hphantom{=} - (1 - 2\epsilon ) \left( 1 - \frac32 \bigl( -K (1-\epsilon)\epsilon \bigr) + \frac1{2!}\frac32 \frac52 \bigl( -K (1-\epsilon)\epsilon \bigr)^2 - \frac1{3!}\frac32 \frac52 \frac72 \bigl( -K (1-\epsilon)\epsilon \bigr)^3 + \cdots \right) 
\end{aligned}$$
Here we have $E_y \propto (1 + 2\epsilon) \cdot A_1  - (1 - 2\epsilon) \cdot A_2 = A_1 - A_2 + 2\epsilon \cdot ( A_1 + A_2)$ where
$$\begin{aligned}
A_1  &= 1 - \frac32 K (1 + \epsilon)\epsilon  + \frac{15}8  K^2 (1 + \epsilon)^2\epsilon^2 - \frac{35}{16} K^3 (1 + \epsilon)^3\epsilon^3 + \cdots \\
A_2  &= 1 + \frac32 K (1-\epsilon)\epsilon  + \frac{15}8 K^2 (1-\epsilon)^2\epsilon^2 + \frac{35}{16}  K^3 (1-\epsilon)^3\epsilon^3 + \cdots \end{aligned}$$
so that
$$\begin{aligned}
A_1 - A_2 & = -3 K \epsilon  + \frac{15}8 K^2 (4\epsilon)\epsilon^2  - \frac{35}{16} K^3 (2 + 6\epsilon^2)\epsilon^3  + \cdots \\
A_1 + A_2 & = 2 - 3 K \epsilon^2  + \frac{15}8 K^2 ( 2+2\epsilon^2)\epsilon^2  + \frac{35}{16} K^3 (6 \epsilon + 2\epsilon^3)\epsilon^3 + \cdots
\end{aligned}$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #4CAF50]{\implies\begin{aligned}[t]
E_y &\propto  -3 K \epsilon + O( \epsilon^3 ) + 2\epsilon \cdot \bigl( 2 + O(\epsilon^2) \bigr) \\
&= (4-3K)\epsilon + O( \epsilon^3 ) 
\end{aligned} }$$

Therefore the critical point $E_y = 0$ is given by
\begin{align} 
4 - 3K &= 0 &&\implies \frac{ 4d^2 }{ x^2 + d^2} = \frac43 && \implies 2d^2 = x^2 &&
\end{align}
which is the desired $x = \sqrt{2} d$.

Comment: I think your answer is right but aren't you using loads of redundant terms in your taylor approximations? It's hard to read..

Comment: I was just trying to provide all the details. Indeed this is routine expansion and nothing particularly profound about it. Since you posted the question here after already got an instruction on the physics site, I presumed you had difficulties wading through the algebra. Whether a particular algebraic manipulation is "redundant" or "helpful" is really personal, and obviously I guessed wrong what you want. If you have already found elsewhere a version (or written up yourself) that is "easy to read" then I'm glad for you.

Comment: Now, about the technical stuff. (1) The choices to denote $\epsilon$ and $K$ as such is intended to make the expressions shorter. You can try other ways (with different multiplicative factors), and most likely you'll end up with more terms and longer equations. (2) The use of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is intended to highlight the parallel and complementarity of the two parts.

Comment: The bottomline is, I'm sorry if my solution as seen (with those designs and intentions ) doesn't work for you. There's the edit functionality, and you can modify my post to suit your needs. Or, you are very welcomed to type up your own approach as a separate answer post and "accept" it, to show future readers a derivation that can be deemed better under some criteria. Editing to improve the content and self-answering are common practice that are encouraged on this site.